# Como utilizar handle_uploaded_file en Django

Tags: python, django

Hola estoy utilizando handle_uploaded_file en Django y me lanza el siguiente error: **MultiValueDictKeyError at /restaurar/ "'file'"**

Aquí les dejo mi código para ver si me pueden ayudar y saber que pasa

Este es el `form.py`:

```
class  Seleccion(forms.Form):
    selec= forms.FileField()
```

Este es el `view.py`:

```
def restaurar(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = forms.Seleccion(request.POST, request.FILES)
        handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES['file'])
        return render(request, 'index.html')
    else:
        form = forms.Seleccion()
        return render(request, 'salvas.html', {'form': form})

def handle_uploaded_file(f):
    with open('upload_salva.sql', 'wb+') as destination:
        for chunk in f.chunks():
            destination.write(chunk)
```

Answer (score 0):

El `request.FILES` es un diccionario donde cada clave o *key* es el nombre que fue insertado en el input del HTML. Quizás tienes varios archivos asociados al mismo *name* del input. Tienes 3 opciones que se me vienen a la mente:

1- Adjudicar un solo archivo al input, o verificar que no haya varios inputs con el mismo atributo *name*.

2- Podrías iterar por el diccionario de FILES:

```
for nombre, archivo in request.FILES.iteritems():
    #archivo2 = request.FILES[nombre] # Esto es lo mismo que contiene archivo
    handle_uploaded_file(archivo)
```

3- O bien podrías extraer (y eliminar del diccionario) un elemento:

```
file, value = request.FILES.popitem()
handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES[file]) # Notece que las comillas no van
```

Espero haber sido de ayuda!

Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Fiate en tu form, el Error está en que tu campo no se llama `file` si no `selec` por ende, es el nombre del key que traera asociado el request.FILES

bastaría con que hicieras

`handle_uploaded_file(request.FILES.get('selec'))`

Espero sea de ayuda